# How to edit Python scripts with correct autocompletion?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I am trying to edit python scripts in first time and it drives me crazy :( .

I have some directory with *.py files, that I added to PyCharm as Interpreter Paths, for correct auto completion.

So, I have some class

```
class Sim():
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._sim_info = None
```

I am Java and C++ programmer and I am used to class type variables.

I know, that in scripts this variable will have value with type `SimInfo`.

But, when indexer of the PyCharm indexed that *.py files, he knows, that `Sim.sim_info` var has value `None`. But how can specify, that in code

```
s1=Sim()
i=s1.sim_info
```

variable `i` has type of class `SimInfo`?

May be I should use something like "editor hits", to force auto completion for `i.is_ghost`?

For example, code

```
from simulation.sims.sim import Sim
from simulation.sims.sim_info import SimInfo
from simulation.sims.pregnancy.pregnancy_tracker import PregnancyOffspringData

s1=Sim()
i=s1.sim_info
i.is_ghos
```

where `i.is_ghos` must be auto completed to `i.is_ghost()`.

How to specify variable types in this case (may be via something like editor hints)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It should happen by default you don't have to turn on anything

Comment: No, it is not (((.

Comment: Did you press tab after `i.i`?

Comment: It will happen, if in `Sim` declaration of the `sim_info` will be something like `    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._sim_info = SimInfo()` . But, in my case, variable declared with `    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._sim_info = None` ...

Comment: It has not any class type value. It's None.

Comment: Hmm.. Strange. It doesn't matter. None is a valid value. And Python doesn't do type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6:

```
class Sim():
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._sim_info: SimInfo = None
```

Other python:

```
class Sim():
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._sim_info = None  # type: SimInfo
```

It called "[type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#d417517e57) with pycharm using the @type docstring.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # n.b., in your usage code you use `.sim_info`
    # but in your constructor you used `._sim_info`
    # since I didn’t see a prop get function, I assumed
    # that you meant `.sim_info`
    self.sim_info = None 
    """@type: SimInfo"""
```

or

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.sim_info = None
    """:type SimInfo"""
```

You can also specify the full path to the class including the module if just the class name did not work.  You can also use PEP484 in PyCharm to specify the type of member variables:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.sim_info = None # type: SimInfo
```